loading the provider_login_url tag on my login page
I'm trying to configure all-auth in my django project and after clicking on my login button
i configured everything in the backend
I'm getting the following error on line 95
TypeError at /accounts/login/
string indices must be integers


95          <a class="google-btn" href="{% provider_login_url 'google' %}>



I've loaded the
{% load socialaccount %}


and this is the button:
  <a class="google-btn" href="{% provider_login_url 'google' %}>
    Log in with Google
  </a>

in settings.py:
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'Fashion',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google'

]

EDIT:
I've managed to solve this issue by downgrading to
django-allauth==0.61.0
django-allauth[google]==0.61.0

